# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

I have application that is connecting to the DB and if I enter incorrect information about DB server I wait a lot of time for responce and in console (MS output) I see a lot of lines like this:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

How I can configure my app that it will return error after first error line : `A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll`. And is it possible or I need to wait long time for exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wait is most likely due to the timeout values in the connection string settings. Lower those values and it will fail faster.

Comment: Yeah... that works, but the whole design is probably broken if this is what they need.

Answer (score 2):

I do have same exception. But there was an issue with the permission to the target SQL database.

Just make sure the that the `User mapping` to the specific user used by the application in to the database.

Just select `db_owner` and `public`.

Hope it works.

Just reply if it solves any body's bugs.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid waiting too long you can set a ConnectTimeout of the connection object to a shorter interval.

Dont know what you mean about "return error after first error line." Can you give an example of what the full message is and what you want?